# Why don't I get an chance to respond to the Extinction Event choice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack, mtg-arena

[Extinction Event](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExtinction%20Event%5d) reads

> Choose odd or even. Exile each creature with converted mana cost of the chosen value.

Why can't I respond to my opponent's choice of odd/even, for example by activating my [Witch's Oven](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWitch%27s%5d%2b%5bOven%5d)? Making this choice is the part of the spell so once the player chooses, shouldn't I be able to react as it still should be on the stack? Is this just an Arena bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You cannot react to the even/odd choice in Extinction Event because that choice is made during the spell's resolution.**

In general, you don't make all kinds of choices while casting a spell. As specified in [rules 601.2b-d](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Casting_spells), you choose modes, splices, other cost modifiers, targets, and how to divide or distribute an effect among targets. Any other choice, like even/odd in Extinction Event, doesn't happen until the spell resolves.

While the choice on Extinction Event may look similar to a modal choice, a modal choice specifically requires you to choose from a list of actions, so an instruction to "choose" other things is different.

---

This fact is also mentioned in a Gatherer ruling on Extinction Event:

> You choose odd or even while Extinction Event is resolving. Players can’t take any actions between the time you make that choice and the time some creatures go extinct.

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly thinking about the modal choice (did not know the name), which is also why it looked weird to me. I should have checked if for rulings first though.

Comment: You also make decisions related to costs during casting, but that's pretty obvious.

Comment: You're right. I expanded that part a little to make it more accurate.